# duvidas com o single page application do angular

Tags: html, angularjs, aplicação-web, single-page-application

sou iniciante com o single page, e gostaria de saber se eu preciso de um servidor para rodar minha pagina web que estou criando com single page? se sim qual o melhor servidor para usar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite Aderbal, depende, você está usando angular 1 ou 2? O angular 2 roda em um servidor node.js a principio e você tem a opção de "transpilar" o código para gerar javascript e html "puro". Se você estiver usando angular 1 você precisa de um servidor sim, pode ser um apache ou até mesmo o próprio node.js, a diferença é que o angular 2 "já vem" com o servidor imbutido, é mais prático. O angular 1 se pensar bem é composto apenas de arquivos .html e .js logo você precisa de alguém que disponibilize esse arquivos para a web no caso o servidor web. O angular 2 também é um set de arquivos .html e .ts (que depois de transpilado vira .html e .js) porém este segundo é bem mais simples e se você seguir a receita de bolo que tem no site do angular 2 você já vai ter um servidor web pronto para uso assim que criar seu projeto. Não sei se consegui ser claro mas vou deixar um link aqui pra te ajudar: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html

Comment: mais claro impossivel. estou usando o angular 1 entao acho que vou usar o apache. muito abrigado victor , foi de grande ajuda...